# How to design a matching network for an ASK 315 MHz receiver?

Tags: rf, antenna, radio, impedance-matching

How to match antena network impedance for a certain receiver frequency. Example how below circuit values are calculated to match the SYN470R receiver for 315MHz. Is there a way to further simplify the network with less components and having same results ?

[image]

Comment: Title: how to design antenna? Answer to that: use a piece of wire / conductor with length \$\lambda/4\$ where \$\lambda\$ is the wavelength of 315 MHz (so the antenna will be around 24 cm long). Yet in question you circle the antenna + matching network. Are you asking how that is designed? Answer: by experimentation and possibly using a **network analyzer**. Be more precise what you are asking.

Comment: L1, L2, C1 and C2 impedance match the antenna (unidentified) to the impedance of the chip (unidentified). Too many things unidentified to properly and succinctly answer this question.

Comment: @Andyaka
thank you for your answer and sorry for my mistake , i mean "matching network".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thank you for your answer and sorry for my mistake , i mean "matching network".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ok

Comment: The information you require is on page 13 at https://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/453934_1928180.pdf

Comment: It seems to me that's already a quite minimal matching network. Of course you can omit the elements you don't need. Also, it depends on the degree of match you need (i.e. performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [chip's data sheet](https://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/453934_1928180.pdf) you can find its input impedance at 315 MHz on page 14.

[image]

You can then model that as a 12 Ω resistor in series with a 3.12 pF capacitor. If you assume a quarter wave monopole antenna, it has an output impedance of 37.5 Ω + 23.8 pF in series. Then, model both and do a simulation: -

[image]

Then run an AC analysis and you get this: -

[image]

So, it's not quite perfect at 315 MHz but, it's not far off. The gain is ~4.4 dB (not too shabby). Maybe it could be tweaked to optimum (12 dB gain) and maybe, if you took into account PCB board capacitances, self-resonant frequencies of the inductors used, it might be better than 4.4 dB of gain.

But, it's also likely that an antenna formed as a PCB pattern is going to have different impedances than for an ideal quarter wave monopole hence, you'd have to do some digging around to find more appropriate values.